# PHP How to include PHP file on current folder or sub folder automatically

Tags: php

I have PHP file `timezone.php` on folder config.

Now I want to include it on my PHP file, example in index.php

```
include("config/timezone.php");
```

This working OK.

And now example, I have another folder call `project`. Inside project have `index.php`

then I include `timezone.php` there.

If I set this:

```
include("config/timezone.php");
```

sure, it will not working.

and the correct way:

```
include("../config/timezone.php");
```

My question:

How to set automatically for including the timezone.php even in sub folder without manually adding `../`?

As you can see I set it manual `include("../config/timezone.php");`, add `../`

Comment: Maybe you should store full path to your woking directory inside some variable. And then call: include($fullPath . "config/timezone.php");

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php ?

```
set_include_path( "path/to/config" ) ;
```